# Locales: Eclipse vs. jar

Tags: java, eclipse, localization, locale, resourcebundle

This is a really simple question that I just don't understand.

I use `messages.properties` files and the `Messages` class (generated by Eclipse) for my localization. I have this code:

```
public class LocaleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Messages.getString("LocaleTest.LocaleTestMessage")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

}
```

And two properties files:

**messages.properties**

> LocaleTest.LocaleTestMessage=This is the locale test.

**messages_es.properties**

> LocaleTest.LocaleTestMessage=Esta es la prueba de locales.

The `messages.properties` and `Messages.java` files are created by Eclipse's "Externalize Strings" function (*Source* → *Externalize Strings...*).

When I run this in Eclipse (via standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) on a Spanish system, it displays "Esta es la prueba de locales," as expected. But when I export to .jar with default options and run from the command line, it prints "This is the locale test."

In a GUI application, the entire application is always in the main language (the strings from `messages.properties`).

I know the files are being exported correctly because it works if I add the following to the top of my messages class:

```
static {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es"));
}
```

I've set my "Default language for non-unicode programs" to "Spanish", as described [here](http://java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml).

So, why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**: Printing `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` yields "English" from the command line. From Eclipse, it prints "español."

Comment: what is the locale set to be in your command line?

Comment: "English"; meant to include that. Sorry.

Comment: What should have been set - environment variables, etc - in the command line for it to be Spanish?  Check it is so.

Comment: It's supposed to determine the locale from the "Current language for non-Unicode programs" (Region and Language control panel), which is "Spanish (Mexico)". I want to be able to double-click a GUI jar and have it run in whatever language the user's system is in.

Comment: Running `set LANG=es` and `set LC_ALL=es` before `java -jar ltest.jar` doesn't change the outcome, but running `java -Duser.language=es -Duser.region=MX -jar ltest.jar` runs as expected (Spanish).